# How can I bind the server root `/` to the index html file in a subfolder `/html/index/index.html`?

Tags: html, apache, xampp

Now I have the following file tree.

```
<SERVER_ROOT>
    ட <html>
          ட <index>
                 ட index.html
                 ட client.min.js
                 ட <img>
          ட <abc>
                 ட abc.html
                 ட ...
          ட <efg>
                 ட efg.html
                 ட ...
    ட <lib>
```

I want to send and display the file **`http://localhost/html/index/index.html`** if the user browse the url **`http://localhost/`** *without redirection*. What configuration should I change or add to the `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: Why you do not set `http://localhost/html/index/` as root? this will fix all your issues

Comment: Some other html file are not in `http://localhost/html/index/` but in `http://localhost/html/abc/xxx.html`.

Comment: Which server side language you are using?

Comment: I am using PHP for server side and ReactJS for client side.

Comment: It is a bit strange that your other pages are located behind your root folder... whatever if you are using php just send a GET parameters which will show you that you are on the root page

Comment: Each folder, for example, `<index>`, `<abc>`, `<def>`, contains an one-page application and its resources. Is there any better file layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `~localhost/index.php` file, use this simple code.
 `require_once 'html/index/index.html';`
If you want to be redirected to the url `http://localhost/html/index/`:
In your `~localhost/index.php` file, use this code.

```
header('Location: html/index/index.html');
```

Comment: that's not a major problem. It occurs because you addressed your javascript file with the reference of your ' html/index/index.html ' file,  like " src = 'client.min.js' ". But with require_once you do not leave the index.php, so keep src =" html/index/client.min.js ".

Comment: Redirection from file1 to file2 changes the reference to file2, but including file2 in file1 doesn't changes the reference. It remains same as of file1.